# How to solve congruence equations like this one: $ 93^2-x^2 \equiv 0\bmod{12^2} $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to solve congruence equations like this one?
$$
93^2-x^2 \equiv 0\bmod{12^2}
$$

What properties can I use to solve it?

Maybe I have chosen a complicated equation, but, if you wish, you can choose another similar equation. The important thing, for me, is the method of resolution.

Comment: There's two issues here: determining if a solution exists, and then finding them if they do. For the first, here you want to learn about the theorems related to quadratic residues, like the law of quadratic reciprocity. For finding them, probably the last step is Chinese remaindering modulo the prime power factors of the modulus. I am not sure of the techniques to solve this for prime power modulus though, others can speak on this. (For this particular equation, it is clear some solutions exist right away, by factoring the left side over the rationals, the question is then finding the rest)

Comment: Observation is the most useful method, for example $$93^2 \equiv 3^2 \pmod{12^2}$$is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Chinese remainder theorem,

$$x^2\equiv93^2\equiv3^2\bmod144\iff x^2\equiv0 \bmod 9\land x^2\equiv9\bmod16$$

$$\iff x\equiv0\bmod3\land x\equiv\pm3\bmod8\iff x\equiv\pm3\bmod24$$